# Do covariates correlated with residuals in generalized linear models make estimates not consistent or other problems?

Tags: correlation, generalized-linear-model, consistency, endogeneity

Do covariates correlated with residuals in generalized linear models make estimates not consistent or make other problems?

Economists raise an issue about endogenous variables in OLS and do some 2SLS with probit.
Not sure if this is related to econometrics.

Comment: The fitting process ensures that residuals are not correlated with covariates, so question seems to be based on incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Or perhaps you mean potential covariates that might have been included in the model but were not. The question needs to be elaborated to make it clear whether this is what you are trying to get at.